# Pass props between components using state hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

sorry if this question is so simple, I want to pass props between components using state hooks, this is the first component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import NewExpense from "../components/Expenses/NewExpense/NewExpense";
import Expenses from "../components/Expenses/Expenses";
import "../components/Expenses/NewExpense/ExpenseForm.css";

const DUMMY_EXPENSES = [
  {
    id: "e1",
    title: "Lego Simpsons",
    amount: 100.5,
    date: new Date(2021, 1, 15),
  },
  {
    id: "e2",
    title: "Lego Mindstorms",
    amount: 200.5,
    date: new Date(2021, 2, 15),
  },
  {
    id: "e3",
    title: "Lego Batman",
    amount: 300.5,
    date: new Date(2021, 3, 15),
  },
  {
    id: "e4",
    title: "Lego Star Wars",
    amount: 400.5,
    date: new Date(2021, 4, 15),
  },
];

const VerExpensesV3 = () => {
  const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState(DUMMY_EXPENSES);
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);

  const addExpenseHandler = (expense) => {
    setExpenses((prevExpenses) => {
      return [expense, ...prevExpenses];
    });
  };

  const statusFormHandler = () => {
    return showForm;
  }

  const showFormHandler = () => {
    setShowForm(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My expenses</h1>
      {showForm && (
        <NewExpense
          onAddExpense={addExpenseHandler}
          statusForm={statusFormHandler}
        />
      )}
      <div className="new-expense__actions">
        <button onClick={showFormHandler}>Add New Expense</button>
      </div>
      <Expenses records={expenses} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default VerExpensesV3;
```

this is the second one:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './NewExpense.css';
import ExpenseFormV2 from './ExpenseFormV2';


const NewExpense = (props) => {
    const [statusForm, setStatusForm] = useState(props.statusFormHandler);
    console.log("el valor de statusForm en NewExpense es: "+statusForm);

    const saveExpenseDataHandler =
        (enteredExpenseData) => {
            const expenseData = {
                ...enteredExpenseData,
                id: Math.random().toString()
            };
            props.onAddExpense(expenseData);
        };


    return (
        <div className="new-expense">
            <ExpenseFormV2
                onSaveExpenseData={saveExpenseDataHandler} 
                currentStatusForm={statusForm}/>
        </div>
    )
};

export default NewExpense;
```

So far I'm stuck because in these lines:

```
const [statusForm, setStatusForm] = useState(props.statusFormHandler);
console.log("el valor de statusForm en NewExpense es: "+statusForm);
```

I get "undefined", from my point of view the value passed is NULL from component 1 to component 2 and I don't understand why, so your comments and suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong property on props in `<NewExpense>`.  Try this instead:

`const [statusForm, setStatusForm] = useState(props.statusForm);`

`statusForm` is the prop you defined on the component, and `statusFormHandler` is the name of the function you assign to the `statusForm` in the first component.

If you actually want your prop name to be `statusFormHandler` then disregard the above and use this

```
<NewExpense
  onAddExpense={addExpenseHandler}
  statusFormHandler={statusFormHandler}
/>
```

Comment: absolutely right, thanks a lot for your solution, I'm in the process to feel comfortable with props and states. Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using lower letter variable name.

```
const newExpense = (props) => {
  const [isDefault, setDefault] = useState(true);

  const saveNewExpenseHandler = (expenseData) => {
    props.onSaveExpense(expenseData);
  };

  return (
    <div className="new-expense">
      <ExpenseForm onSavePressed={saveNewExpenseHandler} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default newExpense;
```

once I changed `newExpense` to `NewExpense` it all worked fine